# Is it possible to test apps from Intel Xdk using the android emulator?

Tags: android, cordova, intel-xdk

I wonder whether it is possible to test a Cordova project made with Intel Xdk on an Android emulator rather than a device on USB or the Intel embedded emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You will have to install and run the APK file you build onto the Android Emulator. Although, I would recommend you build *without Crosswalk* (meaning, uncheck the "optimize with Crosswalk" build settings option) if you are going to run your app on the Android emulator.

However, it's usually a lot faster to just install it directly onto a real Android device and use remote CDT over USB to debug the app. See [this doc page](https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/using-remote-chrome-devtools-to-debug-android-cordova-apps) for help setting up remote CDT on your system.

Of course, there are some system-level debugging things you can do on the Android emulator that can be difficult or impossible to do on a real device, depends on your device.